# Putting a copyright line at the bottom of the screen

Tags: html

I'm trying to build a web page with Kompozer on my Mac. I have a background image 2004px x 1471px. I want a copyright line to appear at the bottom of the screen, but I'm having to scroll right down to see it. I tried reducing the image height to 850px but it just got repeated. How do I do this, please?

Comment: It's 2016, come on. Responsive layouts? People using their phones don't want to download 2,947,884 pixels of background image...

Answer (score 0):

put your image in a footer-div and apply position:fixed css style

put this in the html:

```
<div id="footer"><img src=...></div>
```

this in the css:

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. Footer is still at the bottom of the image, not the screen.